# App sharing within the organization

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, marketplace

How I can share my windows phone 7 app for internal sharing. Like I created on app and I want to share with company stakeholders. Or second case is I made my app for some private company and they don't want to share or publish on marketplace. They just want to use this app for within the company and organization.

Any Idea how we can share this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with the use of Sharepoint.

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointandwindowsphone7trainingcourse_creatingprivateapplicationslab.aspx

I've did some more research, there should be something called a '[enterprise marketplace](http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2011/04/15/mango-adds-beta-and-private-marketplaces-to-windows-phone-7-and-neglects-enterprise/)'.
You still publish you app to the normal marketplace, but only people with the direct (Zune) link can download the app. It is not to be found in the public marketplace.

With the introduction of Windows Phone 8 there will be a possibility to create an '[Company hub](http://techie-buzz.com/tech-news/wp8-enterprise-features.html)'

Answer (score 0):

IIRC when you beta test your application (provided you have a AppHub membership) you can specify a number of private testers for your application, although I think this is limited to around 10.  I don't think you can publish a private application.

[Source](http://www.winrumors.com/windows-phone-app-hub-updated-to-include-private-marketplace-for-beta-apps/)